# No orders possible since PayPal plugin (SwagPaymentPayPalUnified) update 4.30

Tags: paypal, shopware, shopware5

since the latest plugin update from yesterday, which has version 4.3.0 it is no longer possible to place order through paypal.

Shopware version is 5.7.14.

Here are the most recent error logs:

```
[2022-08-16T09:58:34.081601+02:00] plugin.ERROR: PayPal: Could not get PayPal order due to a communication failure {"message":"Client error: `GET https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response","payload":""} {"uid":"08396c6"

[2022-08-16T10:17:09.910750+02:00] plugin.ERROR: PayPal: Could not create PayPal order due to a communication failure {"message":"Client error: `POST https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:\n{\"name\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"details\":[{\"location\":\"body\",\"issue\":\"PAYMENT_SOURCE_CANNOT_BE_USED\",\"description\":\"The  (truncated...)\n","payload":"{\"name\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"details\":[{\"location\":\"body\",\"issue\":\"PAYMENT_SOURCE_CANNOT_BE_USED\",\"description\":\"The provided payment source cannot be used to pay for the order. Please try again with a different payment source by creating a new order.\"}],\"message\":\"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.\",\"debug_id\":\"a85bf6ba371ec\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_SOURCE_CANNOT_BE_USED\",\"rel\":\"information_link\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]}"} {"uid":"666eb45"}

[2022-08-16T12:37:32.629182+02:00] plugin.ERROR: PayPal: Could not update PayPal order due to a communication failure {"message":"Client error: `PATCH https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXX` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:\n{\"name\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"details\":[{\"issue\":\"ORDER_ALREADY_COMPLETED\",\"description\":\"The order cannot be patched  (truncated...)\n","payload":"{\"name\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"details\":[{\"issue\":\"ORDER_ALREADY_COMPLETED\",\"description\":\"The order cannot be patched after it is completed.\"}],\"message\":\"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.\",\"debug_id\":\"9777a181e6a7f\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ORDER_ALREADY_COMPLETED\",\"rel\":\"information_link\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]}"} {"uid":"2298783"}
```

Errors occur from logged in users, guest users, orders with or without shippingcosts.

Even in sandbox-mode, those errors occur.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here with 4.3.0 and 5.7.7

deactivate "In Context Mode" in the Paypal Settings. Works for now.